# Why cannot transfer metadata TB5:Emerald/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssco-snapshots?

Tags: maven-3

I searched for this error, but I did not get any resolution:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata TB5:Emerald/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssco-snapshots (http://nexuspro.ncr.com/nexus/content/repositories/ssco-snapshots/): C:\Users\nn185020\.m2\repository\TB5\Emerald\maven-metadata-ssco-snapshots.xml (Access is denied)
```

From `C:\Users\nn185020\.m2\repository\TB5\Emerald.exe` is uploading in the NExus succesfully, but I am getting the issue related to `maven-metadata.xml`.

How is it accessing `maven-metadata-ssco-snapshots.xml`?